# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number object

Tags: javascript

```
var s = '{"1" : "Sammy", "2" : "Shark", "3" : "Ocean"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(s);

document.getElementById("user").innerHTML =
"Name: " + obj.1 + " " + obj.2 + "<br>" +
"Location: " + obj.3;
```

Error from console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bracket notation to access numeric keys of an object:

```js
const obj = { "1": "Sammy" };
console.log(obj["1"]);
```

Same goes for using some other character, for example `-`:

```js
const obj = { "test-123": "works only with bracket notation" };
console.log(obj["test-123"]);
```

As [gurvinder372](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984039/gurvinder372) suggests, identifier **cannot** be numeric, you tried to access object's property with a number, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code

```
var s = JSON.parse('{"1" : "Sammy", "2" : "Shark", "3" : "Ocean"}');

document.getElementById("user").innerHTML =
"Name: " + s["1"] + " " + s["2"] + "<br>" +
"Location: " + s["3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have numbers after . (dot operator)
you should try using [].

```
var s = '{"1" : "Sammy", "2" : "Shark", "3" : "Ocean"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(s);

document.getElementById("user").innerHTML =
"Name: " + obj[1] + " " + obj[2] + "<br>" +
"Location: " + obj[3];
```